# Asp.Net MVC RequireHttpsAttribute or Response Redirect doesn't work in IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis-6, requirehttps

I am using RequireHttps attribute to redirect Http to Https. It works fine in my dev machine which has IIS7.5 installed. However, it doesn't work in IIS 6 in Windows Server 2003. Thus, I have got Http error 403.4.
I have tried to use Response.Redirect(), it doesn't work either. So it seems that redirection doesn't work properly in II6.
I am using .Net 4, MVC 3, and QA machine is Windows server 2003 with IIS6. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!
huang

Comment: Did you install an SSL certificate on the remote server?

Comment: yes, I installed self-signed certificate on the server

Answer (score 0):

I use IIS6, and `Response.Redirect()` definitely works in at least some cases!

I'd check exactly what's happening when you try either of your options (`RequireHttps`/`Response.Redirect`). Are exceptions being thrown? If not, what's being returned to the client?

You can use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the raw response being returned from the server, which might give some clues. If you're getting an error page, check the full exception text/stack trace.